# Inserting elements from array to the string

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have two variables:

```
query = "String: {} Number: {}"
param = ['text', 1]
```

I need to merge these two variables and keep the quote marks in case of string and numbers without quote marks.

result= `"String: 'text' Number: 1"`

I tried to use query.format(param), but it removes the quote marks around the 'text'. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `repr` on each item in `param` within a generator expression, then use `format` to add them to your string.

```
>>> query = "String: {} Number: {}"
>>> param = ['text', 1]
>>> query.format(*(repr(i) for i in param))
"String: 'text' Number: 1"
```